# JSON File: Separate Word Count for Different Objects with Python

Tags: python, json, text, nlp

For a current research project, I am planning to count the unique words of different objects in a  JSON file. Ideally, the output file should show separate word count summaries (counting the occurence of unique words) for the texts in `"Text Main"`, `"Text Pro"` and `"Text Con"`. Is there any smart tweak to make this happen?

At the moment, I am receiving the following error message:

```
File "index.py", line 10, in <module>
text = data["Text_Main"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The JSON file has the following structure:

```
[
{"Stock Symbol":"A",
"Date":"05/11/2017",
"Text Main":"Text sample 1",
"Text Pro":"Text sample 2",
"Text Con":"Text sample 3"}
]
```

And the corresponding code looks like this:

```
# Import relevant libraries
import string
import json
import csv
import textblob

# Open JSON file and slice by object
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
text = data["Text_Main"]

# Create an empty dictionary
d = dict()

# Loop through each line of the file
for line in text:
    # Remove the leading spaces and newline character
    line = line.strip()

    # Convert the characters in line to
    # lowercase to avoid case mismatch
    line = line.lower()

    # Remove the punctuation marks from the line
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))

    # Split the line into words
    words = line.split(" ")

    # Iterate over each word in line
    for word in words:
        # Check if the word is already in dictionary
        if word in d:
            # Increment count of word by 1
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
            d[word] = 1

# Print the contents of dictionary
for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])

# Save results as CSV
with open('Glassdoor_A.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Word", "Occurences", "Percentage"])
    writer.writerows([key, d[key])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly the key should be `"Text Main"` and secondly you need to access the first `dict` in the `list`. So just extract the `text` variable like this:

```
text = data[0]["Text Main"]
```

This should fix the error message.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed fixed the error message. As output, I am now receiving single letters in column A and numbers in column B. What needs to be changed to check for words instead of single letters?

Comment: Addition: all of the single letters counted refer to the first line of the file while the remaining data is not included in the analysis/output. As mentioned, the code works with full words if not inlcuding the "Text_Main" specification.

Comment: You need to ask a new question on stackoverflow. This should be a pattern for your software development. Write a small piece of code, have a problem with that, find a fix and fix it. Write the next small piece of code and so on. Your question above combines too many moving parts which can each have problems, but each problem in turn hides the next problem.

Comment: That is understood. Let me summarise the essential part in a new question then.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON file has an object inside a list. In order to access the content you want, first you have to access the object via `data[0]`. Then you can access the string field. I would change the code to:

```
# Open JSON file and slice by object
file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
json_obj = data[0]
text = json_obj["Text_Main"]
```

or you can access that field in a single line with `text = data[0]["Text_Main"]` as quamrana stated.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. However, I am now receiving single letters as output. What can be the reason for that as - without the `"Text_Main"` object specification - the code counts full words?

Comment: Addition: all of the single letters counted refer to the first line of the file while the remaining data is not included in the analysis/output. As mentioned, the code works with full words if not inlcuding the "Text_Main" specification.